# Should I ask POI for update on PhD application?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, application

I applied to several top social science programs this cycle, interviewed at two (both fly-outs), and have received a decision at School A.

It has been a month now since I interviewed at School B, but I have not heard a peep from them. I recently spoke with a mentor of mine, and he indicated this likely means they've sent an acceptance to someone and are waiting to hear back from that person before finalizing outcomes. This would therefore mean that I'm unofficially on a waitlist. But I feel like the silence could also mean I was likely rejected, but they haven't sent out rejections yet. If I think hard enough, I can buy into any situation, really. Note that it appears two of the other interviewees have not heard back either (thanks, thegradcafe). We were a group of six.

I would like to know what the current status of my application is, so that I may begin planning for the next stages of my life (!!). Is it okay for me to email and ask my POI (or should I contact someone else?), and what sort of phrasing should I use so that I don't seem pushy?

Thanks.

Comment: ....What's POI?

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly fine to send such an email; academics are aware that candidates need to know these things.

Send a concise email explaining that you have an offer elsewhere (A) and ask when you will hear from B.

> If I think hard enough

I know it's difficult, but try not to second guess the inner workings of admissions committees. It's much less stressful if you email them and ask.